# Using FOR XML to return child queries

Tags: sql-server, xml, performance, for-xml-path

I am doing the subquery below as a parameter in a SELECT statement in SQL Server 2008.  Is there any disadvantage of doing this to get a child query of the parent and parse it out on the server when its returned.  Seems to easy.

```
(
    SELECT ag.Name, ag.[Description], ega.Gender, ag.[Order], ag.[Type]
    FROM GrassrootsHoops.EventAgeGrade ega
    INNER JOIN GrassrootsHoops.AgeGrade ag ON ega.AgeGradeId = ag.Id 
    WHERE ega.EventId = ev.Id FOR XML PATH('AgeGrade'), ROOT('AgeGrades')
) AS AgeGrades
```